# ionic maps template only works in browser

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework

just created a ionic project with the maps template (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-maps) with the command:

```
ionic start MyMap maps
```

When running the project in the browser:

```
ionic serve
```

Google maps map shows perfect. However, if I try to run it in the emulator or device:

```
ionic platform add android
ionic run android // or
ionic run emulate
```

Google maps simply won't load. I get a blank screen with header and footer. Am I missing something? I did not change a single line of code of the project after creating it with the template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issues as you. Removing the following line of code helps.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
'unsafe-eval'">
```

Seems like some security feature, I'm not sure if that line is very important, do it at your own risk.